# SDL UI Menu Button - Mouse Over

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am creating a menu system for my game engine and want to know how to be able to detect when the mouse is over a button. This is simple enough to do when the button is a square, rectangle or circle but I was wondering how to handle irregular shaped buttons.

Is this possible and if it is, does the complexity mean that it is better to simply use a bounding area (square or circle)?

Comment: How are you drawing buttons on the screen?

Comment: @self They would most likely be SDL_Textures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a bitmask out of the texture or surface data. Decide on a rule; for example where the image is 100% transparent or a certain color the bitmask pixel is set to 0 otherwise set it to 1. Do the same for your cursor. When you check for collision simply check if the bitmask bits set to 1 overlap.

Comment: Cool, not sure how to do it but that is enough information for me to be able to find out with some searching.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First what comes to my mind is to use mathematical functions. If you know the equation of the curve you can calculate if the point is under or over it by simply checking if right side of the equation is greater or less than the "y".

So if you have simple `y = x*x` and want to check point (2,1), you substitute it and check:

```
y = 2
x = 1*1 = 1
```

y > 1, point is over the curve. For opposite situation, taking the point (1,2), we get:

```
y = 1
x = 2*2 = 4
```

y < x, point is under the curve.

Comment: How would you convert every button shape to a mathematical equation?

Comment: Hi thank you, while this works for regular shapes - circle, oval, square, rectangle etc what I was really interested in were irregular shapes ie custom images.

Comment: If you know a few points from the curve you can approximate its equation. But if you want to make it working from the custom shaped image, try pixel-perfect collision. Good option is to use PNG files with transparent surroundings. Then you need to check current pixel alpha value, and if it's greater than 0, you hit the button.